# Center div element vertically in Bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Basically this has been bugging me all morning.
I've looked at plenty of other threads but none seem to help me out which is why I'm creating this question.

I simply want to center my div element on my bootstrap page. It seems like a simple issue but I just cannot fix it.

Html:

```
<div class="wizard-box"></div>
```

Css:

```
.wizard-box {
    background-color: green;
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    margin: auto;
}
```

I've created a jsFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/frP2Z/

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
.wizard-box {
    background-color: green;
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -150px;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -150px;
}
```